# Magento 2 - Category not save

Tags: magento-2.1, category

I imported the categories from Magento 1 to Magento 2, after that I can not create categories, the name appears empty in the list.

[image: Look the last subcategory]

I already cleaned the caches, reindex but it does not solve.
This happens when you create subcategories and parent categories. If I try to edit an imported category when saving the name does not change.

[image: The root category appears in the store settings and is selected.]

No error appears in the error logs.

If I enter the database table and change the name of the categories, it works, but by the magento admin nothing is saved.

Magento version: 2.2.3

Can someone help me?

Comment: Did you check memory limit of php ini? did you try with run command of static-content deploy and setup upgrade?

Comment: Yes, I try, but no success. :(

Comment: While Creating category go to Search Engine Optimization Tab & Then Remove the URL KEY Value & Then Try to save Category then it will work. Do Re indexing & Clear Cache Once then try.

Comment: @RaviVarma The URL KEY is empty when I create a new category... This is correct?

Comment: I am facing the exact same problem after data migration.. Any Solution ? @JuniorMaia

Comment: @RaviVarma Any Solution? I am facing the same problem as mentioned.. I have tried increasing memory limit as well as I have tried the reindex command, my cron jobs are also running..

Comment: I have the same issue with... I just see "Category saved succesfully" but no changes have been made.... Neither on creation (all values are empty). I'm using magento 2.2.5 CE

Comment: I could not solve this problem. I have no idea what might be happening.
hello guys, I could not solve this problem. I have no idea what might be happening. :(

Comment: Did you check error log ?

Comment: Hi did you ever solve this?  I am experiencing the same issue following a data import. If I add a new cat then it saves with all fields blank, if I edit an imported category then that becomes blank too.

Answer (score 2):

After days of troubleshooting, the solution described here resolved this for me: [Magento 2.3.2 - Saving categories after data migration causes empty records](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/287463/magento-2-3-2-saving-categories-after-data-migration-causes-empty-records)