# Magento 2.2.5 - Categories are not getting saved in the database

Tags: magento2, database, category, magento-2.2.5, indexer

In my `Magento 2.2.5` Store, When I try to edit the existing categories content and press the save button, the categories content stays the same, there is no change being reflected in the admin panel,frontend as well as the database. Though the save button shows **You saved the category** without any errors.

I have checked that my `cron jobs are working fine`, `I have also increased the memory_limit value to 512 in php.ini`. All the other changes are working fine.

One thing to be noted, that `I have recently migrated the data from magento 1.9`, just in case if it is related to data migration.

The question below is very similar to my problem for better understanding:

[Magento 2 - Category not save](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/237721/magento-2-category-not-save)

Please, give me your suggestions

Comment: just a question. Did you try to reindex ? php bin/magento indexer:reset and then php bin/magento indexer:reindex? Also you should check your logs and try to find an error before we can really help you. Furthermore is it development or production mode?

Comment: I have tried to reindex plenty of times.. But its not helping at all. The store is in developer mode. @SwAt.Be Any help further? The log shows nothing

Comment: i know i had this error once and it was some kind of error. Are you sure your apache or nginx log is not showing anything or your exception.log is not showing? What you can do is go in the save controller from that page and see what the code is doing and die() it on places to see where it is going wrong.

Comment: I have the same issue with... I just see "Category saved succesfully" but no changes have been made.... Neither on creation (all values are empty). All logs seems fine (I'm using a Bitnami certified magento instance on GC platform)

Comment: @IlGala did you find any workaround for this issue?

Comment: I've found where the problem is... By debugging every single query that the `module-catalog` executes, i saw that the `SELECT` statements works correctly, but the `INSERT` and `UPDATE` are missing the request data... But the request contains the forms data. When the controller calls the method `create` of the `objectManager` something messes up.

Comment: Yes,  I am facing the same issue.. The `INSERT` and `UPDATE` statements are causing this issue..I am Still unable to resolve this. If you get to resolve this, do let us know @IlGala

Comment: @IlGala Any progress on this?

Comment: Also experiencing this, have you been able to determine a fix?

Comment: @DanielBlack No